# Testcafe: Native dialog window handeling

Tags: google-chrome, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm trying to upload a file to the site I'm testing (Using Chrome) with Testcafe. Below is my code so far,

```
    await t
        .setFilesToUpload(Selector('input.btn.btn-link.d-none'), file_path)

    await t
          .setNativeDialogHandler(() => true)
                  .click('#Ok');
```

Once I try to upload the file, browser pops up a native dialog window, my options are "Open" / "Cancel". How do I click "Open"  ? Also I don't know how to get the Selector for Open button.

I'm running this on Linux, Java Script. Below is the error,

```
   1) The specified selector does not match any element in the DOM tree.

       > | Selector('#Open')

      Browser: HeadlessChrome 78.0.3904 / Linux 0.0.0
      Screenshot: /app/code/screenshots/2019-12-11_22-28-52/test-2/HeadlessChrome_78.0.3904_Linux_0.0.0/errors/1.png

         71 |            //.handleAlert().click()
         72 |            //.click('#Open');
         73 |
         74 |        await t
         75 |              .setNativeDialogHandler(() => true)
       > 76 |                      .click('#Open');
         77 |
         78 |        const history = await t.getNativeDialogHistory();
         79 |        await console.log(history);
         80 |    }
         81 |}

         at <anonymous> (/app/code/gen_lib/gen_lib.js:76:24)
```

Comment: TestCafe cannot operate with the native browser "Open File" dialog. Usually it's enought to put the file into the <input> element using the .setFilesToUpload action and raise an uploading process (if it does not start automatically). If such scenario doesn't work with your site, please provide a sample page or a public url to reproduce the issue.

Comment: You can see a detailed [description](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/basics/test-file-upload.html) of how to test file upload in TestCafe and inspect a runnable example [here](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-examples/tree/master/examples/upload-files).

Answer (score 0):

```
async uploadFile() {
    await this.t
        .setFilesToUpload(<Your input selector>, [
            'path to file/Image.jpg'
        ])
}
```